# In javascript, functions, variables, classes, modules,... is there a name that stands for all of them?

Tags: javascript

I wondering if functions, variables or other "*stuffs*" in javascript they have the same name call or not. Or you can say that i don't know how to call them at the same time with the same name.

For example I have a library, then I writing documentation for the functions, members, classes, namespaces of my library. Then how do you call *what* im doing, 'documenting "*stuffs*" of my library? ',  or 'documenting "*components*" of my library'? I saw many people call that this is 'public interface', so '**documenting public interfaces of my library**', is that a true way to call?

This question might be very dumb, but I tried my best to describe it, hopefully you guys can help me, thank you so much!

Comment: in javascript they are language constructs. ideas expressed by a programmer are made of that constructs.

Comment: `interfaces` in software engineering is the part of the code that the user /software interacts with, it might be available as UI component, or as a method calls, `components` are the internal working of the software that might have an exposed interface, this is a very big gray area.

Comment: "*Then how do you call what im doing, 'documenting "stuffs" of my library? ',*" I'd call it "documenting your code. If you're documenting things relevant for people who consume your library, you're "documenting the API". Or "writing the public documentation". Or sometimes just "documenting the library". There is no one way to call this.

Comment: If it's a library you're documenting the **API**. Otherwise you're documenting code

Comment: Note that **API** means **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface - basically the **interface** you give programmers to access logic you created

Comment: Don't use the word **interface** though because in programming context interface means something very specific

Comment: Ok so summary, if I have a library and I document it, thats means im documenting the public interface (API) of the library, right? Take the [leaflet library](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html) as an example, what they are documenting are API. And there is no common name for functions, variables, namespaces,... right? Thank you guys so much for these useful lines!

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is terrifically flexible (people got so terrified they made typescript!) - so when you're documenting your code, I'd recommend calling your code entities by their function not their form.

Here's the beginnings of a list:

```
method: anything you can call e.g. doSomething()

class: A constructor with attributes and methods. 

attribute: a variable inside a class.

class method: a method that changes the internal state of a class.

struct: A constructor with attributes but no methods.
```

There's lots of different words that can be used interchangeably:

- `struct` is similar to an `interface`
- `attribute` is sometimes called `property`
- `method` can be called `function`
- `class` can be called `component`

As long as you are consistent within your documentation, it'll look professional enough.

Comment: So do you think these is a name that can call all of them?

Comment: Collectively you could call it an API. So you would title your document "API reference for <Product>".